# Creating USB Disk from bootable CD

Tags: usb, boot, usb-flash-drive

I have a recovery CD ISO image. As my CD drive is not working, I was wondering whether I can create a bootable pen drive out of that?

Comment: What do you run of that bootable CD?

Comment: Symantec system recovery.

Comment: http://www.livecd.com/boot_disk_creator.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[I found a tutorial](http://www.bootdisk.com/pendrive.htm) for you BUT A FEW THINGS YOU NEED TO CONSIDER IN ADVANCE.

1. The PC has to support booting from a USB flash drive. There may be anywhere from 1-3 items to change in the BIOS to make this possible assuming your BIOS supports it. Some bios's may refer to your flash drive as a USB floppy or USB zip.
2. The USB flash drive must support booting from it in general.
3. The flash drive must contain the boot/system files.
4. The flash drive must have bootsector area. This is done with special utilities.
5. References to "A:" drive lines in the autoexec.bat and/or config.sys files you copy to the drive after you make it bootable may result in errors.
6. You "may" have to format your floppy disk first in WinXP before you create a bootdisk as XP may "not" like working later on with a disk formatted otherwise.
7. Included below is a bootable ISO of DOS 7.1 which may be used with some of these methods if you do not have a 1.44 drive.

> Make your flash drive bootable using
>   Bart's mkbt util:
>   http://www.nu2.nu/mkbt/ | Alt:
>   mkbt20.zip
>
> Put a bootable floppy disk in your A:
>   drive or create one using Windows.
>   Download mkbt20.zip and unpack to to
>   new temp folder you create. Go to the
>   temp folder. Extract the bootsector
>   from the bootable floppy disk. eg Open
>   a DOS Window and go to the directory
>   where you extracted MKBT. Type:
>
> mkbt -c a: bootsect.bin
>
> The boot sectors from the bootable
>   floppy disk have just been saved to a
>   file in the temp folder you created.
>
> Format the flash drive in FAT or
>   FAT16.
>
> Copy the bootsector to the flash
>   drive. Open a DOS Window and go to the
>   folder where you extracted MKBT. Type:
>
> mkbt -x bootsect.bin Z:
>
> "Z" represents the flash drive drive
>   Letter. So if your flash drive has
>   another drive letter, then change the
>   "Z" accordingly.
>
> Now you can [grin] "should" be able to
>   copy the utils you need to the pen drive.

There are more methods over at the source if this one doesn't work.

Comment: I don't have floppy. I didn't find bootsect.bin when I extracted the iso using WinRAR

Comment: Did you try the Build Floppy Image part? http://www.nu2.nu/bfi/